# how to launch TurboGears after installation on windows7

Tags: python, turbogears

I tried to install Python TurboGears 2.1 on windows7 with python 3.3 by given instruction on this url (http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/08/14/turbogears-2-setting-up-on-windows/)
after installation when I used command "paster quickstart example" to create a workspace, I got error "paster is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: I wonder if Turbogears 2.1 even works on Python 3; and its development has definitely stagnated. We migrated from TurboGears to Pyramid, which has excellent [narrative documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/#narrative-documentation)

Comment: Actually TurboGears development is far from stagnating. It recently switched to a 3 months release cycle and 2.3.3 just got released 4 days ago: https://plus.google.com/+turbogears/posts/4YdNHkF6ZgA

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 support is available only since **TurboGears 2.3**.

You probably want to follow http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and install the last TurboGears version, versions after 2.3 are usually easier to install as they have far less dependencies and don't require usage of a private index.

If you are forced to use version 2.1 due to project constraint you must downgrade Python version at least to 2.7